# How to check if dynamic checkbox are checked

Tags: c#, .net

I've an application to import some pictures from a folder into another. I use picturebox to show my pictures and have a checkbox next to it. If it's unchecked i dont wanna import them.

So here is my code for creating a checkbox :

```
        public void CreateCheckBox(Form formInstance,int yLocation, int xLocation, int iNumber)
        {
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            box.Name = "cbxName" + iNumber.ToString();
            box.Location = new Point(xLocation+40,yLocation+90);
            box.Visible = true;
            box.Enabled = true;
            box.Checked = true;
            box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbx_CheckedChange);
            formInstance.Controls.Add(box);
        }
```

And my pictureBox :

```
 public void CreatePictureBox(Form formInstance,int iNumber)
        {
            string[] tNomImage = RecupererNomImage();
            PictureBox pbxImage = new PictureBox();
            pbxImage.Name = "pbxName" + iNumber.ToString();
            pbxImage.Image = Image.FromFile(tNomImage[iNumber]);
            pbxImage.Width = 90;
            pbxImage.Height = 90;
            pbxImage.Location = new Point(iXLocation, iYLocation);
            pbxImage.Visible = true;
            pbxImage.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pbxImage.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; 
            formInstance.Controls.Add(pbxImage);
            pbxImage.Enabled = false;
            CreateCheckBox(this, iYLocation, iXLocation, iNumber);
            if (iXLocation+iXSpacing*2 > this.Width)
            {
                iXLocation = XLOCATION;
                iYLocation += iXSpacing;
            }
            else
            {
                iXLocation += iXSpacing;
            }
```

And I wanna know which checkbox is checked so I can export the picture next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume a picturebox will have a name like:

```
pbxName141
```

And its matching checkbox will have a name like:

```
cbxName141
```

You can ask the form for all the checked boxes:

```
var cbs = formInstance.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.Checked);
```

You can convert the checkbox name into the related picturebox name and look up the picturebox by name:

```
foreach(var cb in cbs){
  var pbName = "p" + cb.Name.Substring(1);
  var pb = formInstance.Controls[pbName];
}
```

So many ways to skin this cat..

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods so that they RETURN the control that was created:

```
public CheckBox CreateCheckBox(Form formInstance,int yLocation, int xLocation, int iNumber)
{
    // ... existing code ...
    return box;
}
```

Now you can store a reference to that CheckBox in the `Tag()` property of the PictureBox:

```
public PictureBox CreatePictureBox(Form formInstance,int iNumber)
{
    // ... existing code ...

    CheckBox cb = CreateCheckBox(this, iYLocation, iXLocation, iNumber);
    pbxImage.Tag = cb;

    // ... existing code ...

    return pbxImage;
}
```

Finally, add all of those returned PictureBoxes to a `List<PictureBox>` so you can easily reference and iterate over them. Simply cast the control stored in the `Tag()` property back to a CheckBox and you can determine if each PictureBox should be imported or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<CheckBox> c = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Cast<CheckBox>().ToList();
forech(CheckBox item in c){
if(c.checked){
}
}
```